# How do you actually search for backtick in MySql?

Tags: mysql, escaping

I need to search for strings containing the character ` in mysql
I am trying:

```
select * from transactions where transactions.calculatorCode like "%`%";
```

but it's returning ALL records.
Am I missing something?

Comment: First check if _ANSI_QUOTES_ mode is enabled : `mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;`. if you see it, then you should surround your strings litterals with only single quotes because double quotes will interpret it as an IDENTIFIER (column, table, etc...) and not a string, which is the standard SQL behaviour

Comment: I have the same problem with single quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check if the ANSI_QUOTES mode is enabled on your server

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

If you see it in the results, then you should surround your strings litterals with only *single quotes* because *double quotes* will interpret them as IDENTIFIERS (column, table, etc...) and not strings, which is the standard SQL behaviour.

So your query should become

```
select * from transactions where transactions.calculatorCode like '%`%';
```

Anyway, you should avoid using double quotes to surround your strings because your SQL code portability will be badly affected. Always use single quotes is a rule of thumb.

If it still doesnt work, you can try a REGEXP_LIKE instead:

```
select * from transactions WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(calculatorCode, '`');
select * from transactions WHERE calculatorCode RLIKE '`';
```

Comment: WIth mysql 5.6, REGEXP_LIKE doesn't work like you said. It should be `calculatorCode RLIKE '\`' ` -- please update answer and will accept it. And thanks for the regexp idea!

Comment: @Merc yes I specified 8.0 syntax. I added both